# system() slows down my camera's feedback

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu-12.04, asus-xtion

I an working with opencv and Xtion Pro Live stereoscopic camera on a motion detection project (os: ubuntu 12.04).
 I have managed to detect the moving object, but i want to put a sound when the motion is detected.

I tried it with the

```
system("canberra-gtk-play -f gotcha.wav");
```

command.
The code does properly what i want, but the feedback is slower. 
This results in hearing the sound more than once.

Is there another command that i should use? Could you please tell me why this command affects my camera's feedback?

Comment: I guess it blocks for the time of playing, then returns...

Comment: Should i use another command in order to work properly?

Comment: Either run it from a separate thread, or use the proper sound API.

Comment: Try adding an ampersand... system("canberra-gtk-play -f gotcha.wav &");